# Search for a string in all files inside a folder starting with a particular pattern using terminal

Tags: terminal, grep

How to look for a text through all files inside a folder, where the filenames start with a pattern

for e.g. grep -lr "text-to-find" /path/xyz*

So find "text-to-find" through all files inside a folder where filenames startwith "xyz" inside the folder "path"

I found a few answers online but none of them seem to be working.

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but you can use a text Editor. Open the folder in a text editor and do a search or find in all sub-folders. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of `grep` has the `--include` flag then you can use that to do this:

```
grep -lr --include=xyz* /path
```

If not, or you want something more complicated then that, you can use `find`:

```
find /path -name 'xyz*' -exec grep -l {} \;
```

If your `find` has `-exec +` then using that is much more efficient:

```
find /path -name 'xyz*' -exec grep -l {} \+
```

Comment: where do you put `text-to-find` in your examples ?